# React JS search in Array (character by character)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-map

This is my first program in React. I've as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name : ''
    }
  }
  render() {
  return (
   <>
      <div>
      <label for="searchEmp">Search Person: </label>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.name} id="searchEmp" 
      placeholder="Enter Person's Name" 
      onChange={event => this.setState({name: event.target.value})}/><br/>
      </div>
      {["John","Steve","Alen","Stephen",
      "Smith","Alex","Jack","Andy","Jacky"].map(item => {
      return <div>{item}</div>})}
    </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

In Output, I've something like as

[image]

I want to filter this list character by character. For e.g. When I enter `S` the list should filtered with names starting from `S` as below:

[image]

Next, If I enter `t` after `S` the list should contain only names as:

[image]

and so on. How can I get this? Apart, as a newbie to React, Is my code okay? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HelgiBorg-thanks for this act. I also tried to set images in the same way but failed. Actually I'm not aware of setting the same here. Thanks again.

Comment: @HelgiBorg-BTW, could you please tell me that how can I make image(s) visible in a question while submitting?

Comment: you can find editing help in https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images (remember to click "show more" in the image section). You can also go into editing mode of your post to see how I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all I think the good practice would be ti either keep the list as constant one if it's fixed or some variable at class level,

Scenario you are asking for is preety much like you want to filter out the list each time, so you can filter out the list kept in variable using a function & could return the list from the function to use

```
let namesList = ['ab', 'fg', 'test'];

input = 'a';

let rgxp = new RegExp(input, "g");

function findFilterNames() {
 return namesList.filter(x => x.match(rgxp));
}

test = findFilterNames();
console.log(test);
```

Comment: @vishal-could you please write something in the form of code? For a beginner like me that will me much more understandable. I hope you won't mind for this.

Comment: check this, I think you'll understand better

Comment: @vishal-this is something like the same I practiced in VS with static input(s). But the case I'm trying is with a User Input(s) and in a totally new environment i.e. React. You might be right with your assistance to me. Might be I'm not getting what you want to convey. Anyway, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to answer but apologies in advance if this doesn't work, I've just started to learn React as well.

Whenever you use setState, the component will re-render itself, so keeping that in mind, you could use the following:

Create a function that looks for this.state.name and checks to see if its blank or has an actual value. If it does have a value, it will either use filter or map to run through the name array and return div elements with the values placed inside.
See code below:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { name: '' };
  }

renderNames() { 
this.names =["John","Steve","Alen","Stephen","Smith","Alex","Jack","Andy","Jacky"];
if(this.state.name !== '') {
   return this.names.map((name) => { 
     if (name.includes(this.state.name)){
       return <div>{name}</div>;
     }
   });
} else {
   return this.names.map((name) => { 
       return <div>{name}</div>;
   });
}
}

  render() {
  return (
   <>
      <div>
      <label for="searchEmp">Search Person: </label>
      <input type="text" value={this.state.name} id="searchEmp" 
      placeholder="Enter Person's Name" 
      onChange={event => this.setState({name: event.target.value})}/><br/>
      </div>
      {this.renderNames}
    </>
    );
  }
  }
```

Comment: @Harshith-throwing Warnings as `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.`,`Warning: Invalid DOM property for.`,`Warning: value prop on input should not be null.` Same is happening with me but in some other way(s). I think this is called a learning phase or stage. By the way, good attempt.

Answer (score 0):

**I will keep it simple and easy**, you must use a function in Javascript called `filter()` with `includes()` function.

I will assume the search term that coming from the input called `term`, and the array that you need to filter it called `names`

```
 const names = ["John","Steve","Alen","Stephen","Smith","Alex","Jack","Andy","Jacky"];

 let term = "s";

 const searchResults = names.filter(name => {
                        return name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
                    });
// the result will be array that contain the following ["Steve","Stephen","Smith"]
```

when you `consloe.log(searchResults)` you will have `["Steve","Stephen","Smith"]` because term value is "s" so you get the all names that have "s" character.

***We change the array items to lowercase using `toLowerCase()` to avoid the case-senstive if there is character upper case***

you can test the code [here](https://stephengrider.github.io/JSPlaygrounds/) just put the name of the filtered `searchResults` at the end of the code

I see this way as the fastest way to search by character.

this is a repo as an example using **Reactjs** :
https://github.com/Tawfeekamr/react-search-in-array-character-by-character.git

Comment: @TawfeeqAmro-i want you to see my code once. My input(s) are coming from a `textBox` namely `Search Person` i.e. User is entering and 2ndly I've to apply filter on already created array namely `item`. Where I'm stucking is when I'm comparing User's input(s) for matching element(s) present in an array namely `item`. So with the same, can you please help me in my existing code?

Comment: You can see my repo as an example:
https://github.com/Tawfeekamr/react-search-in-array-character-by-character.git

Comment: If you need more help just put your code in a repo or any online service to clone it and fix it.

Comment: @TawfeeqAmro-this worked. But what about If I want to get the same using a "Class Component" not a "Function Component". For that where and what changes are I need to make? If you've done this before using a "Class Component" kindly share that one too. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I added the class component to the repo enjoy! @soloLearner

Comment: @TawfeeqAmro-throwing `'NameItem' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef` error when used class component from the repo. Do I've to add something like `import NameItem from 'xxxxxx';` at top left just after `import './App.css';` or is there some other way to get this fix?

Comment: yes yes i forget to push it... now it's working

Comment: @TawfeeqAmro-again this worked fine. A little more I want to add a check that After filtering an array If I take a step back one by one(by pressing Backspace/deleting values) from my "textField", the list should get added back with all non matching values. It's happening but when "textField" gets empty, list is not rolling back by it's own with all names available(My Expectation) instead showing names only that were matching with the "first" alphabet I entered to filter this array. I'm getting my expected result by refreshing a tab which I don't want to do. I hope I'm clear with my query.

Comment: you can add [ if condition ] when the input sends an empty value, set the original array.

Comment: @TawfeeqAmro-I tried by adding [if condition] but failed to get the original array by its own when "textField" is empty. Can you please update your repo by solving this case. Apart, now I'm @ 2nd phase of my program where I’m changing "array" to "array of objects". Now my Data is something like `let student=[{ name: 'Roony', about: 'He is a student'},{ name: 'Rocky', about: 'He is a player'},{ name: 'Ronny', about: 'He is a singer'}];` to filter from. All I want to perform the same like before on this "array of objects". but I'm stucking in this too. Please help me on your repo for both cases.

Comment: @soloLearner did you fix the problem?

Comment: @soloLearner so please set the correct awnser from the answers that you get.